# using jquery to create a list of variables

Tags: jquery

I have a button, when the button is clicked, I want the variable 'name' to be added to my table

```
$('#myTable').click(function(id){
    $('#Selection table').each(function (i) {
        i = i+1;
        $(this).prepend('<tr><td><a><p><b>1st name:</b>' + name + '" </a></tr></td>')
    });
});
```

This code works! however, when the button is clicked a second time, I want the variable 'name' to be appended to the table ('name' is getting changed in the parent function). This code nearly works, however it adds the name variable to the table twice.

I would also like to find a way to label the second click with '2nd' and then '3rd' etc.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you know that you are appending invalid markup? You don't close the `p` tag and close the `tr` and `td` incorrectly.

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i` in the function? You're not even using it.

Comment: If you want to add labels like "2nd", "3rd", you'll need an external variable that keeps a count of the number of times they've clicked.

Comment: Are there really multiple tables under `#Selection`, and you want this row to be added to all of them? If not, you don't need `each()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep track of the times #myTable is clicked you could do the following (I also fixed the invalid markup:

```
var timesClicked = 0;   
$('#myTable').click(function(id)
{
    $('#Selection table').each(function (i)
    {
        $(this).prepend('<tr><td><p><a href="#"><b>1st name:</b>' + name + '" </a></p></td></tr>');
        i++;
    });
    timesClicked++;
});
```